# Block multiple users using Tweepy?

Tags: python, twitter, anaconda, tweepy

Using Tweepy on anaconda3, I can block a single user.
How do I block multiple users? There are 10k users. for the hurdle
How can I remove a username from the list such as excel, txt and block it?

```
# calling the api  
api = tweepy.API(auth) 
  
# the screen name of the user 
screen_name = "xyzz"
  
# blocking the user 
api.create_block(screen_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Twitter's API only allows blocking a single user with each request.
You'll have to loop over your list of users and block them one at a time.